# Find Hard Disk Serial number from Remote SQL Server Installed Hard disk

Tags: c#

I have a C#.net Windows form Application with SQL Server. My application use in Multiple user by local Network. Now I need to find Hard disk Serial Number which hard disk  installed sql server (Note: By Using C#.net Application Data source ).

How can i find Hard disk Serial number throw by application data source?

Comment: **Why** do you need the serial number of the harddisk where the data files of your database reside? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to protect my application by Hard Disk Serial number. I am success for single user in this approach. Now i want to apply same approach for multiple user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections;

namespace WmiControl
{
    public class WMI
    {
        public bool GetDiskSerial(string Computername)
        {

            try
            {
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Computername + @"\root\cimv2");
                scope.Connect();
                ArrayList hdCollection;
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;
                if (GetDiskDrive(scope, out hdCollection, out searcher) || GetDiskSerial(scope, hdCollection, ref searcher))
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;
            }
            catch (ManagementException)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        private bool GetDiskSerial(ManagementScope scope, ArrayList hdCollection, ref ManagementObjectSearcher searcher)
        {
            try
            {


                ObjectQuery query1 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

                searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query1);
                int i = 0;
                string sDiskSerial = "";
                foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
                {
                    // get the hard drive from collection
                    // using index
                    if (i < hdCollection.Count)
                    {
                        HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];
                        if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
                            hd.SerialNo = "";
                        else
                            hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                    }
                    ++i;
                }
                foreach (HardDrive hd in hdCollection)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hd.SerialNo))
                    {
                        sDiskSerial = hd.SerialNo;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool GetDiskDrive(ManagementScope scope, out ArrayList hdCollection, out ManagementObjectSearcher searcher)
        {
            try
            {
                ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
                hdCollection = new ArrayList();
                searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
                {
                    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
                    hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
                    hd.Type = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
                    hdCollection.Add(hd);
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                hdCollection = null;
                searcher = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    class HardDrive
    {
        private string model = null;
        private string type = null;
        private string serialNo = null;
        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { model = value; }
        }
        public string Type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set { type = value; }
        }
        public string SerialNo
        {
            get { return serialNo; }
            set { serialNo = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

[See here for more info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlnetfx/thread/aaaeda1c-22dc-47f0-b0ff-6adc7aa8f1ac)

[You might want also to study CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131077.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to resort to WMI. With the proper privileges on the SQL Server machine, you can get the serial number of the hard-drives on it. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6077/How-to-Retrieve-the-REAL-Hard-Drive-Serial-Number) for an example on retrieving the hard-disk's serial number using WMI.

You'll need to figure out which disk holds SQL Server and how to access the SQL Server machine on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in 3 stages:

- The connection string of the data source gives you the name of the machine on which SQL Server is installed
- You must then query the machine to find out the drive which drive SQL Server is installed on
- You can then use the code supplied by others here to get the serial number